# Varying a percentage based on actual result

Tags: probability

I have a desired percentage, 33%, and a 100-sided dice. I also have the number of times the dice has been rolled, and the number of times the dice roll has been successfully under the desired percentage.

How would I go about changing the desired percentage to match the real results? Such that when the dice has been rolled 3 times and succeeded 1 time, the target is the default of 33. Yet when the dice has been rolled 4 times and succeeded 1 time, the target increases (and so becomes easier), and when the dice has been rolled 3 times and succeeded 2 times, the target decreases (and becomes more difficult) by going down to around 16. It's also important that the target never reaches 100% or 0%, ideally capping out at 99% or 1% for a really long string of lucky/unlucky rolls.

If you could post an example with the actual numbers plugged in that would be super helpful, too.

Comment: So what you want is what weighting future rolls need to return to the mean? You won't get a closed form unless you limit the number of future rolls somehow.

Comment: Basically the target for each dice roll is changed each roll, based on the number of tries vs successes to attempt to return towards the base, which is 33%. So 3 tries 1 success would be 33 for the next roll (normal), 4 tries 1 success would be around 41 (too many tries), 3 tries 2 success would be around 22 (too many successes).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you want to roll a d100 numerous times, changing the success threshold to try to keep the number of successes close to 33%.  This is not enough information to formulate an answer.  One simple approach would be whenever the fraction of success is less than 33%, make the threshold 99 so you almost always succeed.  When it is greater than 33%, make the threshold 1 so you almost always fail.  It sounds like you want something smoother than that.  You could do something like threshold=33-2(current-33)=99-2current, applying your cap to 1 or 99 at the end.  You could change the multiplier from 2 to suit you.  This one is continuous, but has corners, which could be smoothed.  There are many more.

Comment: What more information would be needed? Also when you say "current" do you mean (successes / tries)? I commented on my original post to hopefully make it clearer. And yeah something smooth is ideal, so it's not immediately obvious what the result would be, eg. if you have 4 tries and only 1 success you can't go "Well I'll definitely succeed next roll!"

Comment: @Mortlanka:  yes, current is the successes/tries just before a roll.  The equation I gave is continuous, but is a linear ramp with corners at the start and end.  Plot it and see if you like it.

Comment: So with 3 tries and 1 success: 33-2((1/3)-33)=98.333? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Mortlanka:  I was using current as a percentage, which seemed to be what you were doing.  So with 3 tries and 1 success $33-2(33\frac 13-33)=32\frac 13$ then you round

Comment: Ah, okay. .33-2*((1/3)-.33) definitely appears to work when tries increases, but if successes increases beyond 50% I start getting negatives. 2 tries and 1 success gives me -0.01. Sorry if I'm doing this wrong, I've only got a regular old calculator to work with.

Comment: @Mortlanka:  that is true, but you shouldn't get above 50% except at the very start.  With a few tries done the percentage doesn't change quickly and as you go toward 50% it will get less and less likely that you succeed.  You can truncate at 1 and 99 after calculating.  You could also decrease the multiplier-that sets how fast the success rate should change as you go away from 33%, which is only dependent on your taste.

Comment: That's unfortunate, as I'm mainly looking for something that will scale between 1 and 99. The formula works great for below 50%, but that's just half the problem. This is mainly intended for smaller amounts of tries since just a raw 33% will trend towards that given a long enough time.